# How to prove that a version of a program is more memory efficient?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management

I have an application which has to process hundred of thousands of records. Right now, I can only process 500 of them at a time. Each batch can take up to 5 minutes to process/analyze (total of ~10 hours of processing). The reason for that limit of 500 records is memory consumption. I think that one of the main reason why our program takes so much memory is that fact that we don't set the size of lists or dictionaries (e.g. new List() instead of new List(100000)). I did the changes to set the size of collection so that .NET stop creating and copying new lists with extra capacity.

Here's my question: how to prove that a version of a program is more memory efficient? Are there performance counters I should look at? Tools? Monitoring?

Comment: You could start by looking at number of GC cycles.

Comment: Redgate has a good profiler that should do the job nicely.

Comment: A more efficient version will take less than 10 hours.

Answer (score 3):

There are tools like [.net memory profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) from where you can have in-depth analysis of memory management and memory leaks of a .net application.

> .NET Memory Profiler is a powerful tool for finding memory leaks and optimizing the memory usage in programs written in C#, VB.NET or any other .NET Language. With the help of the profiling guides, the automatic memory analyzer, and specialized trackers, you can make sure that your program has no memory or resource leaks, and that the memory usage is as optimal as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a profiler would give you a real overview of how much more efficient one version is than the other.

I recommend using memory performance counters to do this. You can setup a few data collection sessions using `perfmon`, for both of your app's versions.

You should monitor at first only the [process memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#process_memory_performance_information) (of your process, of course). You can also add some of the rest of [system memory performance counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx#XSLTsection131121120120), just to see how the overall virtual memory status changes during your process' lifetime.

If there is a difference and you still can't get a good overview and conclusion, you could start digging in the [.NET CLR memory performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx). Not as easy to analyze than the previous ones I mentioned, but much more detailed.

You should probably run each session for one hour or two in order to get some good data, given the lengthy processing done by your app.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand if you do happen to look into Memory profiling then [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) does let you record performance counter data with its results/snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built Performance Profiler tool if you have Visual Studio Ultimate: **Debug -> Start Performance Analysis**. If you don't have this available, you can use [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) by JetBrains, which accomplishes the same thing.

You can also measure execution time by using the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. Stopwatch is specifically designed to measure elapsed time and may (if available on your hardware) provide good granularity/accuracy using an underlying high-frequency hardware timer, compared to DateTime.Now. By using the Stopwatch class and comparing the two execution times you can see which runs faster. This does not give any information with CPU or Memory Usage.

Answer (score 1):

Using lots of memory does normally not really slow you down until you go out of real memory and start using swapfiles. You can check that in Task manager while your app is running. Where you can also see the peak and working amount of memory of your app.

I would profile a bit (there are several memory profilers available) to see what objects are taking up your memory.

As for the lists; I do not think setting the capacity of Lists will fix your problem. The List class grows by doubling the capacity (tested as I could not find documentation). Worst case you are using twice the memory. If you create new lists inabundance you could create an object cache to re-use the lists. But in my experience .NET this does not help much in .NET as the runtime is quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLR GC ETL events. Download perfview from Microsoft, run your application under it, and then just check the GC page.

Just check "total memory allocation" and "time spent in GC" would give you an idea of how managed memory is used.

If you want more details, check the CLR allocation tick events.

Perfview can also analyse your managed heap live objects.